# Replacing Handlebarjs's escaper

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm working on a setup that runs a bunch of shell commands on a remote system when triggered. Instead of having a bunch of concatenated strings, for maintainability I decided to use a templater.

Handlebarjs has so far proven to be amazing, but by default it html encodes output. I've learned you can add `{ noEscape: true }` to the compile command, or wrap the variable in {{{ }}}, but what I'd like to do is for certain templates, replace the default escaper entirely. Is this doable?

Right now my templates look like:
`mkdir \"{{shellEscape directory}}\"` with noEscape turned on, but I'd rather default that behaviour.

Failing that, I'd like to know if there is a Util function that translates the variable provided to a string (You can provide handlebar a function, but a helper doesn't evaluate it first)